# Openwrt documentation describing web interface

Tags: openwrt

I'm looking for a documentation/tutorial for OpenWRT 15.05 that would describe router web interface. My company is using OpenWRT for one of our IoT node, and it needs to have custom WiFi web interface where we would be able to choose the network the node connects, do the connection test to our server and few other features.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout https://github.com/openwrt/luci/wiki

OpenWRT uses LUCI as web interface. It can be customised, but one should know LUA.